# How to hide Get data from Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to hide get variables from url.now my url showing like this
http://www.example.com/supplier/dashbord.php?name=MyRest

i want to show url something like 
http://www.example.com/supplier/dashbord.php

also i tried .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /supplier/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^supplier/(.*) dashbord.php?name=$1
</IfModule>
```

but it's did't work.is there any solution for me?

Comment: What you want - to hide `?name=` or `MyRest` ?

Comment: I think they want anything hidden after `*.php`

Comment: @Kristiyan do you need the value `MyRest` ?

Comment: i want to hide `?name=MyRest`

Comment: If you want to pass information via the URL is has to be displayed somewhere. The server can't just guess what you want. You can make the url look like /supplier/$id if you think that's prettier but the information still needs to be there.

Comment: @Krycke i want to just hide passed data from user.how can i do  like this /supplier/$id

Comment: The answer from Patrik should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`GET` parameters are always passed with the url.

What you actually want are `POST` parameters, they are transmitted within the http-body rather than the url and therefore invisible for the average user.

In php, you access them by `$_POST['var']` instead of `$_GET['var']`, and in an HTML-form, you simply use `method="POST"` instead of `method="GET"` to transmit form data within the http body.

Comment: You should only use the verb POST to insert things in the database and the verb GET to select things from it. So even if this might solve the OP's question it's not a correct way of doing it.

Comment: Since the REST standard is heavily flawed, I would prefer using POST instead of server configuration and RewriteRules. It also depends on what OP is actually trying to do, maybe he wants to insert data in a database?

Comment: It's true that it depends on what the OP wants to do. Personally I think it's wrong though if it's a select that should be done.